# Creating Multiple Values to Same Key in Dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I currently have two different arrays and I want to store them under the same index number in a dictionary such as:

### Dictionary (Desired Result):

```
{1: ([-1.95364833, -2.3406949 , -1.78136408, ...,  2.20188999,
             2.44994974,  1.11205757], 50.), 
2: ([-2.23099494, -2.56195164, -1.7833544 , ...,  2.1898737 , 2.55687737,  1.91171312], 42)}
```

**Index Keys:**

```
array([[   0],
       [   1],
       [   2],
       ...,
       [1997],
       [1998],
       [1999]])
```

**Value No.1:**

```
array([[50.],
       [42.],
       [46.],
       ...,
       [46.],
       [60.],
       [46.]])
```

**Value No.2:**

```
array([[-1.95364833, -2.3406949 , -1.78136408, ...,  2.20188999,
         2.44994974,  1.11205757],
       [-2.23099494, -2.56195164, -1.7833544 , ...,  2.1898737 ,
         2.55687737,  1.91171312],
       [-1.91742587, -2.31495118, -2.00310111, ...,  2.10471678,
         2.31442952,  1.38450444],
       ...,
       [-2.17547345, -2.25906157, -1.8122977 , ...,  2.04136801,
         2.66251564,  1.73665702],
       [-2.25692463, -2.60385466, -1.83966994, ...,  2.11042762,
         2.52533793,  1.98603952],
       [-1.93614006, -2.27099538, -2.02284527, ...,  2.20629144,
         2.48619676,  1.36994064]])>
```

### Current Attempt

```
embedded_dict = {}

for key in index_array:
    for value1, value2 in zip(embeddings, temp_array):
        embedded_dict[key] = value1
        embedded_dict[key] = value2
        embeddings.remove(value1)
        temp_array.remove(value2)
        break
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: try `zip(index_array, embeddings, temp_array)` remove the extra for loop and use `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure on how you reference this? would it be something like? embedded_dict = {}

for i in zip(index_array, embeddings_array, temp_array):
    embedded_dict(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example of an easy way:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [10, 20, 30]
my_dict = {}

for index, (value1, value2) in enumerate(zip(arr1, arr2)):
    my_dict[index] = [value1, value2]
```

Comment: thanks, that is definitely what I'm looking for :) I got something like this, {0: [array([-1.95364833, -2.3406949 , -1.78136408, ...,  2.20188999,
          2.44994974,  1.11205757]),
  array([50.])],
 1: [array([-2.23099494, -2.56195164, -1.7833544 , ...,  2.1898737 ,
          2.55687737,  1.91171312]),
  array([42.])]